# On hovering #leaderboard, add a class to #left-arrow and #right-arrow

Tags: jquery, hover

Sorry for such a basic question, but I need to know how to add a class to two divs, #left-arrow and #right-arrow when I hoverover #leaderboard.

I understand I can use the call hover(), but I'm unsure how to implement it to add a class on another element.

I'm definitely a beginning with Javascript, so the more specific on how to implement it the better! Thanks!

-Judson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), like this:

```
$("#leaderboard").hover(function() {
  $("left-arrow, #right-arrow").toggleClass("myClass");
});
```

This adds the class when you hover, removed it when the mouse leaves.  If you want to *just* add the class, then [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) will work and you can manually remove it with [`.removeCass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) later.

For this part:

> I understand I can use the call hover(), but I'm unsure how to implement it to add a class on another element.

Just use a selector like I have above, you're not restricted to using `this` inside *any* function, you can use [a selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) or [traverse functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to move around wherever appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate you breaking it down for me- especially the $(this) part. I'm from a Photoshop background, so development is another world to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#leaderboard').hover(function() {
  // This first function is the hoverIn handler, when the user hovers over #leaderboard
  $('#left-arrow, #right-arrow').addClass('yourClassName');
}, function() {
  // This second function is the hoverOut, when the user stops hovering over #leaderboard
  $('#left-arrow, #right-arrow').removeClass('yourClassName');
});
```